# About onSubmit and how I should use it

Tags: javascript, select, onsubmit

So I am trying to create four select menus within a form that give the user several item options/combinations.

So basically they can chose different values from all four select menus and onSubmit the user will be taken to the correct URL. Example (Agra -- Blue/Aqua -- Traditional -- $99-$199) and the url for that filter will direct the user.

The question I have is how should I go about defining a function for something like this?

I essentially need the form (we already have the URLS for every combo) to direct the user to the appropriate url when they click submit. Part of me thinks this is a very inefficient way of doing things and that I should be using jQuery or something.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It's one select element with four options, each option with different url? Or it's four select, and they relate somehow? Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: It's four select elements with varying options. 1 will have 50 options and 2 will have 12 options, 3 will have 4options, and 4 will have 5options. They are related ... in the select menu one will be a rug, menu 2 will be color, menu 3 will be style and menu 4 will be price range

Comment: http://www.safavieh.com/rugs that product filter is a good example of what I want ...... I need help please not looking for someone to write it out just need a better understanding of whats involved. THanks

Answer (score 0):

When using the drop down option each listing contains a value. depending on what values you set you could create a filter to locate the correct URL.

Also depending on ur URLS you could create them with the values of the drop down menu.

You might want to consider adding a search button so u know when the user has selected all of the options.

Comment: Ok I understand the first bit. The problem is there is probably 300-400 URLs that I would have to assign, would doing it manually be the best way or is there something I can use to decrease the time it'll take. Can you explain a little more about the filter and what within JS I Should use? Sorry for so many newb questions